Is there a function to recreate the code to produce a plot from the ggplot object itself
Is there a function that allows me to recreate the code used to produce a plot from the plot object itself?
For instance:
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point(aes(color = Species))

bluid_code(gg)
# Expected output (as text):
# ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point(aes(color = Species))

Note:
There seems to be such a function in the shinymeta package. However, it has to be used within a Shiny app.

Have you looked at the contents of your gg object?

@CarlWitthoft there's a very large amount of information stored in the gg object. I couldn't spot the code itself. In principle, the gg object should contain all the information necessary to rebuild the code. Just wondering if there's a function that does that or if it is already hidden somewhere in the content of the object.

Not all that much info, aside from the large $data array containing what's actually used in the plot.  Take a look and I think you'll see that the name of the original data source is not stored, so you are out of luck.

That's too bad, would've been super useful. Thanks!

@CarlWitthoft, post as an answer?

@BenBolker  I'll defer to the referenced question that Mr. Flick found :-)
